# Possible race condition calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`displayModal` has a value that is always a value behind.  Possibly a race condition.  I call `updateModal` in the callback for `setState` so a race condition should not happen.

```
      addAccrual: function() {
        console.log('setting modal to display true');
          this.setState({displayModal: 1}, this.updateModal());
      },

      saveAddAccrual: function() {
        console.log('setting modal to display false');
          this.setState({displayModal: 0}, this.updateModal());
      },

      cancelAddAccrual: function() {
        console.log('setting modal to display false');
          this.setState({displayModal: 0}, this.updateModal());
      },

  updateModal: function() {
    console.log("state of displayModal: " + this.state.displayModal);
    if(this.state.displayModal){
      console.log('showing modal');
      $('#myModalOverlay').show();
      $('#myReactModal').show();
    }else{
      console.log('hiding modal');
      $('#myModalOverlay').hide();
      $('#myReactModal').hide();
    }
  },
```

E.G.

> Setting modal to display true 
>   state of displayModal: 0 
>   hiding Modal

HTML/JSX

```
<button className="ay-btn" id="addAccrualButton" onClick={this.addAccrual}>Add Accrual</button>

<button className="btn" type="button" onClick={this.cancelAddAccrual}><i className="icon-remove"></i>Cancel</button>

<button className="btn-primary btn" type="button" onClick={this.saveAddAccrual}><i className="icon-white icon-ok"></i>Save</button>
```

Comment: Because multiple `setState` calls can be collapsed into a single one. In other words not every `setState` call is guaranteed to actually call your callback.

Comment: js is single threaded. there are no race conditions.

Comment: Myeah and it turns out I misinterpreted "the value of this.state is not guaranteed to update right away". It's asynchronous but it guarantees the callback will be called after the operation completes and for every `setState` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably this:

```
this.setState({displayModal: 1}, this.updateModal());
```

I assume you want to call `updateModal` after the state has successfully been set. the above line doesn't do that, since you're passing *the result* of `updateModal` as a callback.

Change it to:

```
this.setState({displayModal: 1}, this.updateModal); // no ()
```

and you should see the behavior you expect.

Comment: Wow. Did not even look after stuff like that.